# How to calculate the time difference between two event in R?

Tags: r

I have a question regarding an algorithm that I don't know how to solve.

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Time Dose ID
0     0   1
0.1   1   1
0.2   0   1
0.3   0   1
0.4   1   1
0.5   0   1
0.7   0   1
0     0   2
0.2   0   2
0.3   1   2
0.4   0   2
0.6   0   2
0.8   1   2
0.9   0   2
1.0   1   2
1.5   0   2
```

There's many subjects in the dataset, with each subject dosed at different times. What I want to calculate is to calculate a column of data, which is the time after last dose for each subject. Since each subject is dosed several times, how do I update the number of time subtracted from the R program? Thank you!

The expected look would be:

```
Time Dose ID TPD
0     0   1   0
0.1   1   1   0
0.2   0   1   0.1
0.3   0   1   0.2
0.4   1   1   0
0.5   0   1   0.1
0.7   0   1   0.3
0     0   2   0
0.2   0   2   0.2
0.3   1   2   0
0.4   0   2   0.1
0.6   0   2   0.3
0.8   1   2   0
0.9   0   2   0.1
1.0   1   2   0
1.5   0   2   0.5
```

Comment: Can you update with the expected output column based on the example showed

Comment: can you dput your dataset? thanks!

Comment: @akrun It's been done!

Comment: shouldn't `Time Dose ID TPD`
`0.2   0   2   0.2` be `0.2   0   2   0` ? line 9 in your expected table i.e patient `id=2` at time 0.2 has not been dosed hence the time is still zero.

Comment: `dat$TPD =  with(dat, ave(Time , list(cumsum(Dose), ID) , FUN=function(x) c(0,cumsum(diff(x)))))` gives you your output but i am not sure your required output matches your text. Should the output of second row of id2 by `0.0` instead of `0.2` as they have not been dosed?

Comment: @user20650 Thanks a lot. I used your method got what I wanted.

Comment: Youre welcome Xinting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(ID, Time) %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(TPD=(Time-cummax(Time*Dose))*cummax(Dose)) %>% ungroup
```

***Data***

```
df <- data.frame(Time=c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.5),  
             Dose=c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), 
             ID=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
```

If your data is not sorted then:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(ID, Time) %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(TPD=(Time-cummax(Time*Dose))*cummax(Dose)) %>% ungroup
```

Comment: Hi Dimitris. May I ask what does the symbol %>% means in your solution? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Xinting WANG, it is called chaining or piping, it is an easy alternative to nested syntax. More on that at http://seananderson.ca/2014/09/13/dplyr-intro.html near the end there is an "An awesome example". Enjoy